# flask altering python list

Tags: python, flask, chart.js

I'm trying to propagate data into a bar chart using CHARTJS, it requires I make a list out of the data. I was able to send the data points through but not the labels.

```
MYLABELSLIST = list(df['column'])

''' This yields:
['Mar 20','Apr 20','May 20','Jun 20','Jul 20','Aug 20','Sep 20','Oct 20','Nov 20','Dec 20','Jan 21','Feb 21'] 
'''
```

I then go into my index.html

```
                 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {

                                type: 'line',
                                data: {
                                    labels: {{ MYLABELSLIST }},
                                    datasets: [{
                                        label: "Data",
                                        borderColor: gradientStroke,
                                        pointBorderColor: gradientStroke,
                                        pointBackgroundColor: gradientStroke,
                                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: gradientStroke,
                                        pointHoverBorderColor: gradientStroke,
                                        pointBorderWidth: 4,
                                        pointHoverRadius: 2,
                                        pointHoverBorderWidth: 1,
                                        pointRadius: 1,
                                        fill: true,
                                        backgroundColor: gradientFill,
                                        borderWidth: 2,
                                        data: {{ myDataList }}//[11, 12, 4, 9, 10, 12, 8, 10, 11, 12, 12, 12]
                                    }]
                                },
```

I'm getting the following error:

[image]

As you can see it looks like it changing the output of the list:
[image]

My hunch is that its converting the single quotes for whatever reason. I tried using `json.dumps()` which would convert the list into double quotes instead of single. The same issue persisted.

I tried this and it did not work as well:

```
var MYLABELSLIST = {{ MYLABELSLIST | safe }}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This solved it:

`labels: {{ MYLABELSLIST  | safe }}`

For safety reasons Jinja is escaping the html code.
' is the html code for an '

Information about jinja's html escaping can be found here: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#html-escaping